# Orchestrating containers

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to use the Kubernetes to deploy Docker Container and I found [this tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux-atomic-host/version-7/getting-started-with-containers/#creating_a_kubernetes_cluster_to_run_docker_formatted_container_images).

So according to this tutorial, what is the prerequisites?
They said that "services that are typically on a separate Kubernetes master system and two or more Kubernetes node systems are all running on a single system."

But I don't understand how we run both master and nodes on a single system (for example I have one instance EC2 with IP address 52.192.x.x)

Answer (score 2):

That is a guide about running Kubernetes specifically on RedHat Atomic nodes. There are lots of guides about running Kubernetes on other types of nodes; see the [Creating a Kubernetes Cluster](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/README.html) page on docs.k8s.io.

One of the guides on the Kubernetes site shows how to run a [local docker-based cluster](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.html), which should also work for you on a single node in the cloud.

Comment: I dont want to run as a single node. I want do "DEPLOY" between master and node using Kubernetes. And the documentation on the home page is absolutely old.

Comment: The documentation I linked to is for the latest stable release (1.1). If you want to build from head, you can use the corresponding documentation in Github directly.

Comment: The best way to deploy manually while understanding how each component is setup and which are the prerequisites is probably to read through [Getting started from scratch](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch.md). It feels like you're trying to setup something which you do not understand in the first place.